# ListView in windows 8 JavaScript to get click on Item

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-8, winjs

i am using following code to get ListView, Suppose i wanted to click on any particular item need to go in detail page how can i ?

```
 <div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
        data-win-options="{itemDataSource : RenttheRooRental.itemList.dataSource, 
            itemTemplate: mediumListIconTextTemplate, layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout}, oniteminvoked : handler}">
    </div>



 <div id="mediumListIconTextTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template" class="">
        <div id="menu" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;">

            <!-- Displays the "picture" field. -->
            <a href="URL:url">
                <img src="#"
                    data-win-bind="alt: title; src: picture" />
            </a>
            <div>

                <!-- Displays the "title" field. -->
                <h2 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h2>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can any one guide me ? if you dot know the question please comment i will explain again
thanks

Comment: Yug - as a side comment, you may have issues with your template because  above you declare your template _after_ you declare your listview. I've had issues with that before. If you swap your mediumListIconTextTemplate div with the basicListView div, you should be better off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [HTML ListView essentials sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-basic-usage-sample-fcc451db) on MSDN.

Your ListView already defines a handler called `handler` in its `data-win-options` attribute.

In the code behind, you need to create that event handler:

```
function handler(eventObject) { 
    eventObject.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) { 
        // In here, you can use invokedItem.index and invokedItem.data
    }); 
}
```

Comment: lt me try, i hope it will work, as i want. i want like A B C D are in ListView, if i click on A it will lead me to A detail only

Comment: You need to provide more detail around what the detail area is like. If it's a simple div on your page, the handler can simply update the div when it's invoked. If it's a different page, you'll need to do a navigation and pass as an argument the item details. One of the default templates in Visual Studio 2012 will show you the technique. Please post more details if you're stuck!

Comment: here it is best example i think
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974582.aspx